# Sample variables from two columns in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have tried to sample values of two columns that are related (diversification rates of several siter groups), but I have no idea of how to do it. I am trying with `sample` function, but it limits me so I cannot choose any further condition.

```
    df<-data.frame("M"=c(0.06,0.14,0.05,0.07), "H"=c(0.06,0.08,0.04,0.05))
    df
#      M    H
# 1 0.06 0.06
# 2 0.14 0.08
# 3 0.05 0.04
# 4 0.07 0.05

    sample(df,size=1000,replace=TRUE)
```

When I use this command, it resamples rows and columns:

```
     H    M  M.1  M.2  M.3
1 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.06
2 0.08 0.14 0.14 0.14 0.14
3 0.04 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05
4 0.05 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07
...
```

But I want it to only sample one value from each row, and go to the next row with the same condition until the end of the rows. Finally, when there are no more rows, it should start all over again up to `size=1000` so I can have a vector of length 1000.

Example of what I want (r = row, c = column): `0.06`(r1c1), `0.14`(r2c1), `0.05`(r3c1), `0.05`(r4c2), `0.06`(r1c2), `0.14`(r2c1),`0.03`(r3c2), `0.07`(r4c1) and so on.

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDITED:

I think that what I am looking for is something like a loop function, but I still do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should first create an indexing matrix of two columns (row index and column index), then index the original matrix with it.

```
idx <- matrix(c(rep(1:4,250), sample(1:2, 1000, replace=T)), ncol=2)
res <- as.matrix(df)[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

With your specifications, you'll need to use a custom function.

Here's one small way to do it:

```
myfunc <- function(dataframe, nsamples = 1000){
  rows = ((0:nsamples)%%nrow(df)) + 1 #use the %% to get the row to sample
  cols = sample(ncol(df), nsamples, replace = TRUE) #and the cols
  sapply(1:nsamples, function(x){df[rows[x],cols[x]]}) #sapply to get as a vector
}
 myfunc(df,10)
 [1] 0.08 0.05 0.07 0.06 0.08 0.05 0.05 0.06 0.08 0.05
```